# HTML onclick events causing innerHTML performance degradation

Tags: javascript, performance, onclick, innerhtml

I'm encountering a bizarre issue and believe additional eyes on the problem can help.

We are doing performance testing for our application in Internet Explorer 8. We have a table view and in the first column is an  anchor tag that one can click to launch a modal window. We have noticed an issue where inline click events are causing the call to innerHTML to slow down by as much as 2 seconds with a large number of rows (around 150).

Upon investigating, I found that if every row has the same parameters passed to the inline onclick, performance is fast. Here is a sample of what that html looks like...

```
<dl id='a' class='result-info odd'>
            <dd id='b' class='table-cell'><a
                    onclick='javascript:SampleNamespace.LaunchModal(10.0);'>Column 1</a></dd>
            <dd id='b' class='table-cell'>Column 2</dd>
            <dd id='c' class='table-cell'>Column 3</dd>
</dl>
```

Of course, that content is repeated 150 times.

Now, if I change it such that each row has a **different** value passed to SampleNamespace.LaunchModal, performance degrades.

Has anybody else encountered this situation? Any clues as to why innerHTML performance would degrade when using inline onclick? My current theory is that innerHTML is doing some sort of processing when it encounters the onclick and there are optimizations when parameters are the same.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Why have an inline click event in the first place? Add a data attribute and listen for the click on the table body.

Comment: Yeah, that's our solution to the problem. Unfortunately we have a lot of code using that and our deadline prohibits us from re-working everything that uses these inline click events.